# Why does Kojirou say "white hole" in the Japanese version of Team Rocket's motto?

Tags: japanese-language, pokemon

Torisuda mentioned he'd be interested in how the joke went in the Japanese version of Pokemon on my [question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/30201/17758) about why Team Rocket's motto seems so nice. This prompted me to listen to the Japanese version of the motto on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7CNNYFhqdk).

I came across this line in the Japanese version of Team Rocket's motto where Kojirou says:

> **コジロウ**: ホワイトホール、白い明日が待ってるぜ

Why does he say "Waito Hooru" (White Hole) here?

Comment: "white hole" as in the "opposite" of an astrophysical black hole. Why? Who knows. I'd say probably because it sounds cool? cf. http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q149157244, http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/259543.html.

Comment: It does kind of go with the whole rocket/space theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There used to be an interview about the production of Pokemon and they did explain it. The phrase translates to "white hole, white future awaits us". Sometimes, however, it can also translate to "bright future awaits us". That's why they wanted to use white, and the hole part of it is because it's a pun. Team Rocket and white holes, rocket and space which has black holes in it, get it? Rocket goes into space and there are black holes in space, but we need the color white so it became white hole. If this doesn't make sense, then leave a comment and I'll try to put it into other words. Unfortunately, I can't find the interview anymore, but hope this helps.

Comment: I think it makes sense, it's just a terrible pun? Is that all?